# Remove Read More Buttons

Tags: themes

I am simply trying to get rid of the Read More button on my blog posts.

I would like my blog to show my full article.

Comment: which theme you are using? or any particular plugin you are using. because without this info. we cant help you.

Comment: Any plugin for posts?

Comment: No, no plugin for posts

Answer (score 0):

This theme already have options for this in `appearance` menu

```
Go to appearance -> theme options -> Styling Settings -> Posts on Homepage to full posts
```

Comment: Okay, where exactly do I add it in the sheet? Sorry I know this is a newbie question but I have no idea.

Comment: You're not removing anything. You're just hiding it...

Comment: Sorry for that i just updated my answer. reply me if it work

Answer (score 0):

You can add this PHP code to functions.php in your theme.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

This will remove all read more buttons in your theme. But if you just want to show complete articles **without excerpt** this you can achieve by customizing  WP Settings. See image below.
[image]

Comment: That setting is just for RSS feeds. How the posts display on the front-end is determined by the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Check also that wherever you want the (full) content displayed the template is using the_content(); NOT the_excerpt();

Answer (score 0):

I went to Appearance - Customize -  "Whatever Theme " Theme Options - Blog Section Options - here i selected the "content" option instead of "excerpt" from the Show content form tab